# Multiple Price Options -

Tags: price, option

I am trying to have multiple price options for books, for example Book A - hardcover will be $20 and softcover will be $16.00

But I want it to display the price as "$16-$20" or say "Price Varies" 
right now what I do is create a custom option and have a drop down, but the base price is $16 and it says "hardcover + $4.00"  That I know how to do, but I want it on the category page where it says the products to show "$16-$20" or "price varies" is there such a way?

Comment: Use this extension instead https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-absolute-price.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve what you're wanting would be to use Bundle Products.

Then you would create 2 simple products 1 Soft Cover and 1 Hard Cover. Combine these products within a bundle product and you will then get the Price from $16 to $20 and be able to select the choice within the product.

This guide may help further: [Solving Magento: Bundle Products](http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-bundle-product-type-part-1/)